# Update a VCL component from CreateAnonymousThread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe

It seems which [Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Synchronize) cannot be used  from a Thread created using [CreateAnonymousThread](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread), so the question is : `How i can update a VCL component from inside of a Thread created using CreateAnonymousThread?`

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
 begin
  //do something
  UpdateCompnent();//how I can update a VCL component from here?   
 end
).Start;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You **can** use synchronize in this case, e.g.:

```
TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin UpdateComponent(); end);
```

And if you want asynchronous method call execution within the main thread, you can use `TThread.Queue`, e.g.:

```
TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin UpdateComponent(); end);
```

Comment: @David: That OP uses/asks about synchronize may just be because he wants to avoid threading issues, not necessarily because he needs synchronous execution.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use PostMessage to safely queue, or SendMessage to safely synchronize from an anonymous thread.

Comment: +, because I always favor `PostMessage` for component synchronization over the `Synchronize` method: no chance of dead-locks, no waiting in the working thread. But it does require a bit more work.

Comment: PostMessage isn't comparable with Synchronize.

Comment: If you need to get a bit of data (state) from a background thread and out into the foreground thread, safely, quickly, and without side effects or bugs, it's entirely comparable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PostMessage(Form.Handle, WM_UPDATEMYCOMP, 0, 0);

You can define your own message id, wparam, lparam, with a bit of work you can turn them into more complicated parameters.

Comment: You mean SendMessage rather than PostMessage in this situation.

Comment: Note that accessing the `TWinControl.Handle` property from a worker thread context is not thread-safe.  If the `Handle` is being recreated during that time, such as by a call to `TWinControl.RecreateWnd()`, then the thread can end up taking owership of the new `HWND` (and the main thread leaks an `HWND`), causing the `TForm` to stop working correctly.  If you need to pass messages to a main thread `HWND` from a worker thread, use the `TApplication.Handle` window or the `AllocateHWND()` function instead.